# AWS S3 auto save folder

Tags: amazon-s3, autocad-plugin

Is there a way I can autosave autocad files or changes on the autocad files directly to S3 Bucket?, probably an API I can utilize for this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to quickly find a plug in that does that for you, what you can do is one of the following:

1. Mount S3 bucket as a drive. You can read more at [CloudBerry Drive - Mount S3 bucket as Windows drive](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/drive/amazon-s3.aspx)

This might create some performance issues with AutoCad.

2. Sync saved files to S3

You can set a script to run every n minutes that automatically syncs your files to S3 using `aws s3 sync`. You can read more about [AWS S3 Sync here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). Your command might look something like

```
aws s3 sync /path/to/cad/files s3://bucket-with-cad/project/test
```